# I need help adding keyboard focus to my Buttons

Tags: button, sass, focus, material-design

I'm creating some Material Design buttons and I'm having some issues getting keyboard tab focus to work with my buttons. Ideally what I would like to do is mimic the effect found in Material UI when you tab through patterns:(https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/), However, I would be happy with just getting focus to work.

I've tried adding class: focus to no avail. Any help would be appreciated

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/JohnDangerous/pen/qYZQwo?editors=1100)

```html
<!-- header -->
<header>
  <h2 tabindex="0">Material Design Buttons</h2>
</header>
<!-- @end header -->

<!-- Main content -->
<main role="main">
  <section>
  <h3 class="heading">Raised Buttons</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="holder col-4">
      <div class="demo"><button class="rkmd-btn btn-lightBlue" tabindex="0">Primary</button></div>
      <div class="captions">Normal Button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder col-4">
      <div class="demo"><button class="rkmd-btn btn-lightBlue ripple-effect" tabindex="0">Primary</button></div>
      <div class="captions">keyboard Focus</div>
    </div>
     <div class="holder col-4">
      <div class="demo"><button class="rkmd-btn btn-lightBlue ripple-effect" tabindex="0">Primary</button></div>
      <div class="captions">Ripple Effect</div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder col-4">
      <div class="demo"><button class="rkmdgrey-btn" disabled tabindex="0">Primary</button></div>
      <div class="captions">Disabled Button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <h3 class="heading">Raised Buttons Secondary</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="holder col-4">
      <div class="demo"><button class="rkmdWhite-btn  Nutrien-greenSecondary" tabindex="0">Secondary</button></div>
      <div class="captions">Normal Button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder col-4">
      <div class="demo"><button class="rkmdWhite-btn  Nutrien-greenSecondary ripple-effect" tabindex="0">Secondary</button></div>
      <div class="captions">Ripple Effect</div>
    </div>
        <div class="holder col-4">
      <div class="demo"><button class="rkmdWhite-btn  Nutrien-greenSecondary ripple-effect" tabindex="0">Secondary</button></div>
      <div class="captions">Keyboard Focus</div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder col-4">
      <div class="demo"><button class="rkmdgrey-btn" disabled tabindex="0">Secondary</button></div>
      <div class="captions">Disabled Button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

  <section>
  <h3 class="heading">Raised Buttons</h3>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="holder col-4">
      <div class="demo"><button class="rkmdYellow-btn $Nutrien-green" tabindex="0">CTA</button></div>
      <div class="captions">Normal Button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder col-4">
      <div class="demo"><button class="rkmdYellow-btn $Nutrien-green ripple-effect" tabindex="0">CTA</button></div>
      <div class="captions">Ripple Effect</div>
    </div>
        <div class="holder col-4">
      <div class="demo"><button class="rkmdYellow-btn $Nutrien-green ripple-effect" tabindex="0">CTA</button></div>
      <div class="captions">Keyboard Focus</div>
    </div>
    <div class="holder col-4">
      <div class="demo"><button class="rkmdgrey-btn" disabled tabindex="0">CTA</button></div>
      <div class="captions">Disabled Button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!--   <section>
    <h3 class="heading">Raised Buttons Yellow</h3>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="holder col-3">
        <div class="demo"><button class="rkmdYellow-btn $Nutrien-yellow">Button</button></div>
        <div class="captions">Normal Button</div>
      </div>
      <div class="holder col-3">
        <div class="demo"><button class="rkmdYellow-btn $Nutrien-yellow ripple-effect">Button</button></div>
        <div class="captions">Ripple Effect</div>
      </div>
      <div class="holder col-3">
        <div class="demo"><button class="rkmd-btn btn-lightBlue" disabled>Button</button></div>
        <div class="captions">Disabled Button</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section> -->
<!--   <section>
    <h3 class="heading">Link Buttons</h3>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="holder col-3">
        <div class="demo"><button class="rkmd-btn btn-link">Button</button></div>
        <div class="captions">Link Button</div>
      </div>
      <div class="holder col-3">
        <div class="demo"><button class="rkmd-btn btn-link ripple-effect"><i class="material-icons">favorite_border</i>Button</button></div>
        <div class="captions">Ripple Effect</div>
      </div>
      <div class="holder col-3">
        <div class="demo"><button class="rkmd-btn btn-link" disabled>Button</button></div>
        <div class="captions">Disabled Button</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section> -->
  <section>
    <h3 class="heading">Buttons in Different Colors</h3>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="holder col-4">
        <div class="demo"><button class="rkmdTert-btn btn-white ripple-effect ripple-dark" tabindex="0">Tertiary Link</button></div>
        <div class="captions">White</div>
      </div>
      <div class="holder col-4">
        <div class="demo"><button style="border: none;" class="rkmd-btn btn-black ripple-effect" tabindex="0">Lorem Ipsum</button></div>
        <div class="captions">Black</div>
      </div>
<!--       <div class="holder col-4">
        <div class="demo"><button class="rkmd-btn btn-grey ripple-effect ripple-dark"><i class="material-icons">file_download</i>Download</button></div>
        <div class="captions">Grey</div>
      </div>
      <div class="holder col-4">
        <div class="demo"><button class="rkmd-btn btn-lightBlue ripple-effect"><i class="material-icons">file_download</i>Download</button></div>
        <div class="captions">Green</div>
      </div> -->
  </section>
<!--     <section>
    <h3 class="heading">Fab Buttons</h3>
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="holder col-3">
        <div class="demo"><button style="background: #ffffff; border: none; shadow: none;" class="rkmd-btn btn-fab btn-lightBlue ripple-effect"><i style="color: black;" class="material-icons">attach_file</i></button></div>
        <div class="captions">Normal Button</div>
      </div>
      <div class="holder col-3">
        <div class="demo"><button class="rkmd-btn btn-fab-mini btn-pink ripple-effect"><i class="material-icons">favorite_border</i></button></div>
        <div class="captions">Mini Button</div>
      </div>
      <div class="holder col-3">
        <div class="demo"><button class="rkmd-btn btn-fab-mini btn-lightBlue" disabled><i class="material-icons">cloud_upload</i></button></div>
        <div class="captions">Disabled Button</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section> -->
</main>
```

```scss
// Buttons Color
$Nutrien-green: #00B455;
$Nutrien-green--hover: #00DD68;
$Nutrien-greenSecondary: #FFF;
$Nutrien-greenSecondary--hover: #00DD68;
$Nutrien-yellow: #F9E051;
$Nutrien-yellow--hover: #E9CE1A;
$Nutrien-disabled: #DFDFDF;


$btn_default: #e0e0e0;
$btn_lightBlue: #00B455;
$btn_white: #FFF;
$btn_black: #111;
$btn_grey: #f5f5f5;
$btn_orange: #ff9800;
$btn_amber: #ffc107;
$btn_green: #4caf50;
$btn_teal: #009688;
$btn_cyan: #00bcd4;
$btn_indigo: #3f51b5;
$btn_deepPurple: #673ab7;
$btn_pink: #e91e63;
$btn_red: #f44336;
$btn_yellow: #ffeb3b;
$btn_lime: #cddc39;
$btn_brown: #795548;

// KEYFRAMES
@mixin keyframes($animation-name) {
  @-webkit-keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    @content;
  }
  @-moz-keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    @content;
  }
  @-ms-keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    @content;
  }
  @-o-keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    @content;
  }
  @keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    @content;
  }
}
// Column generator
@mixin colmk($numRows, $margin) {
  width: ((100% - (($numRows - 1) * $margin)) / $numRows);

  &:nth-child(n) {
    margin-right: $margin;
    margin-bottom: $margin;
  }

  &:nth-child(#{$numRows}n) {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

/* -----------------------------------------------------
  Body
-------------------------------------------------------- */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #646360;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: #eee;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: #03a9f4;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
}

/* -----------------------------------------------------
    Main
-------------------------------------------------------- */
main {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 1.4rem auto;

  section {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1.4rem;
    padding: 1.2rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.157);

    &:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }

    .heading {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    .wrap {
      overflow: hidden;
      display: block;
      margin: 1rem 0 0.8rem;
      text-align: center;

      .holder {
        float: left;
        //display: inline-block;
        //margin-right: 8px;
        //margin-bottom: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #fff;

        &:last-child { margin-right: 0; }

        &.col-3 {
          //width: calc(100% / 3 - 8px);
          @include colmk(3, 1%);
        }
        &.col-4 {
          //width: calc(100% / 4 - 9px);
          //&:nth-child(4n) { margin-right: 0; }
          @include colmk(4, 1%);
        }

        .demo {
          min-height: 120px;
          padding: 2em 0;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-content: center;
        }

        .captions {
          padding: 8px;
          color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
          font-size: 13px;
          font-weight: bold;
          border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 860px) {
          &.col-4 {
            @include colmk(3, 1%);
          }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
          float: none;

          &.col-3,
          &.col-4 {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;

            &:nth-child(n) { margin: 0; margin-bottom: 14px; }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    padding: 0 1.5%;
  }
}

/* -----------------------------------------------------
   Header
-------------------------------------------------------- */
header {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

  h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px 0;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
}

/* -----------------------------------------------------
    Footer
-------------------------------------------------------- */
footer {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 80px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #EEE;

  .row {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 860px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .footer-content {
    margin: 0 8px;
    padding: 25px 0 18px;
    text-align: center;

    span {
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.525);
      font-size: 0.857em;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    span {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
    }
  }
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Material Design Raised Buttons - by Ravikumar Chauhan
------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.rkmdTert-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #00B455;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-family: arial;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;

  &:hover { }
}

.rkmd-btn {
  border: 1px solid $Nutrien-green;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #00B455;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-family: arial;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.225);

  &:hover { text-decoration: none; box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.225); border: 1px solid $Nutrien-greenSecondary--hover; }
}

.rkmdgrey-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #A1A1A1;
  background-color: #DFDFDF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-family: arial;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.225);

  &:hover { text-decoration: none; box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.225); }
}


.rkmdWhite-btn {
  border: 1px solid #00B455;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #00B455;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-family: Arial;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.225);

  &:hover { text-decoration: none; box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.225); background: $Nutrien-green--hover; color: white; 
  border: 1px solid $Nutrien-greenSecondary--hover;}
}

.rkmdYellow-btn {
  border: 1px solid $Nutrien-yellow;
  background-color: #F9E051;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 2px 16px 0 16px;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-family: Arial;
  letter-spacing: .8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.225);

  &:hover { text-decoration: none; box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.225); background-color: #E9CE1A;  border: 1px solid $Nutrien-yellow--hover;}
}


/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Material Design Fab Buttons - by Ravikumar Chauhan
------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.rkmd-btn {
  &.btn-fab,
  &.btn-fab-mini {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: normal;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    &:hover { box-shadow: 0 4px 11px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.375); }
    i {
      display: inline-block;
      float: none;
      width: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: inherit;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: none;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  }
  &.btn-fab {
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  &.btn-fab-mini {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

/* Buttons Color */
.rkmd-btn {
  &.btn-lightBlue {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_lightBlue;
    &:hover { background-color: lighten($btn_lightBlue, 8%); }
  }

  &.btn-white {
    color: #444;
    background-color: $btn_white;
    &:hover { background-color: darken($btn_white, 2%); }
  }

  &.btn-black {
    color: #bdbdbd;
    background-color: $btn_black;
    &:hover { background-color: lighten($btn_black, 8%); }
  }

  &.btn-grey {
    color: #757575;
    background-color: $btn_grey;
    &:hover { background-color: darken($btn_grey, 4%); }
  }

  &.btn-orange {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_orange;
    &:hover { background-color: lighten($btn_orange, 8%); }
  }

  &.btn-amber {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_amber;
    &:hover { background-color: lighten($btn_amber, 8%); }
  }

  &.btn-green {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_green;
    &:hover { background-color: lighten($btn_green, 8%); }
  }

  &.btn-teal {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_teal;
    &:hover { background-color: lighten($btn_teal, 8%); }
  }

  &.btn-cyan {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_cyan;
    &:hover { background-color: lighten($btn_cyan, 8%); }
  }

  &.btn-indigo {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_indigo;
    &:hover { background-color: lighten($btn_indigo, 8%); }
  }

  &.btn-deepPurple {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_deepPurple;
    &:hover { background-color: lighten($btn_deepPurple, 8%); }
  }

  &.btn-pink {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_pink;
    &:hover { background-color: lighten($btn_pink, 8%); }
  }

  &.btn-red {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_red;
    &:hover { background-color: lighten($btn_red, 8%); }
  }

  &.btn-yellow {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_yellow;
    &:hover { background-color: darken($btn_yellow, 13%); }
  }

  &.btn-lime {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_lime;
    &:hover { background-color: darken($btn_lime, 8%); }
  }

  &.btn-brown {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: $btn_brown;
    &:hover { background-color: lighten($btn_brown, 8%); }
  }
}

/* Raised Buttons Size (Not work in Fab Buttons) */
.rkmd-btn {
  &.btn-lg {
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
  }

  &.btn-sm {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  &.btn-xs {
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0 .4rem;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: .2px;
  }
}

/* Raised Buttons Types */
.rkmd-btn {
  &.disabled, &[disabled] {
    cursor: default !important;
    color: #9e9e9e !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }

  &.disabled:not(.btn-flat), &[disabled]:not(.btn-flat) {
    background-color: #cdcdcd !important;
    &:hover { background-color: #cdcdcd !important; }
  }

  &.btn-flat {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    &:hover { background-color: #cecece !important; box-shadow: none !important; }

    &.disabled:hover,
    &[disabled]:hover { background-color: transparent !important; }
  }

  &.btn-link {
    color: #3949ab !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;

    &:hover {
      text-decoration: underline !important;
      background-color: transparent !important;
      box-shadow: none !important;
    }

    &.disabled,
    &[disabled] {
      color: #9fa8da !important;
      text-decoration: underline !important;
      background-color: transparent !important;
    }

    &.disabled:hover,
    &[disabled]:hover { background-color: transparent !important; }
  }

  i {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    line-height: inherit;

    &.right {
      float: right !important;
      margin: 0;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
  }
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Material Design Ripple Effect - by Ravikumar Chauhan
------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.ripple-effect {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 1;

  .ripple {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    transform: scale(0);
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  &.ripple-dark {
    .ripple {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) !important;
    }
  }

  &.ripple-red {
    .ripple {
      background: rgba(244,67,54,0.725) !important;
    }
  }

  &.ripple-orange {
    .ripple {
      background: rgba(255,152,0,0.725) !important;
    }
  }

  &.ripple-yellow {
    .ripple {
      background: rgba(255,235,59,0.725) !important;
    }
  }

  &.ripple-green {
    .ripple {
      background: rgba(221,104,100,0.725) !important;
    }
  }

  &.ripple-purple {
    .ripple {
      background: rgba(156,39,176,0.725) !important;
    }
  }

  &.ripple-teal {
    .ripple {
      background: rgba(0,150,136,0.725) !important;
    }
  }

  &.ripple-pink {
    .ripple {
      background: rgba(233,30,99,0.725) !important;
    }
  }

  .animated {
    animation: ripple 0.6s linear;
  }

  @include keyframes('ripple') {
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: scale(2.5);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ripple-effect').rkmd_rippleEffect();
});

(function($) {
  $.fn.rkmd_rippleEffect = function() {
    var btn, self, ripple, size, rippleX, rippleY, eWidth, eHeight;

    btn = $(this).not('[disabled], .disabled');

    btn.on('mousedown', function(e) {
      self = $(this);

      // Disable right click
      if(e.button === 2) {
        return false;
      }

      if(self.find('.ripple').length === 0) {
        self.prepend('<span class="ripple"></span>');
      }
      ripple = self.find('.ripple');
      ripple.removeClass('animated');

      eWidth = self.outerWidth();
      eHeight = self.outerHeight();
      size = Math.max(eWidth, eHeight);
      ripple.css({'width': size, 'height': size});

      rippleX = parseInt(e.pageX - self.offset().left) - (size / 2);
      rippleY = parseInt(e.pageY - self.offset().top) - (size / 2);

      ripple.css({ 'top': rippleY +'px', 'left': rippleX +'px' }).addClass('animated');

      setTimeout(function() {
        ripple.remove();
      }, 800);

    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly, but if your problem is to make the focus after pressing the tab, maybe the tabindex HTML attribute may help you. It basically defines the order of focus elements on your forms. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Comment: I gave that a try. It's in the code now. For some reason it's not working. I have it in the codepen.